# Lowest common ancestor of two leaves in a tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree

I have the following tree structure:

```
struct Node {
   int data;
   Node* parent = nullptr;
}
```

Where each node has at most one parent but can have many children. I am trying to find the lowest common ancestor of two nodes (node1 and node2) who do not have any children.

This is my current code:

```
std::vector<Node*> ancestors1;
std::vector<Node*> ancestors2;
temp_node = node1->parent;
while(temp_node!=nullptr) {
    ancestors1.push_back(temp_node);
    temp_node = temp_node->parent;
}
temp_node = node2->parent;
while(temp_node!=nullptr) {
    ancestors2.push_back(temp_node);
    temp_node = temp_node->parent;
}
Node* common_ancestor = nullptr;
if (ancestors1.size() < ancestors2.size()) {
    ptrdiff_t t = ancestors1.end() - ancestors1.begin();
    std::vector<Node*>::iterator it1 = ancestors1.begin();
    std::vector<Node*>::iterator it2 = ancestors2.end() - t;
    while(it1!=ancestors1.end()) {
        if (*it1 == *it2) {
            common_ancestor = *it1;
        }
        ++it1;
    }
} else {
    ptrdiff_t t = ancestors2.end() - ancestors2.begin();
    std::vector<Node*>::iterator it2 = ancestors2.begin();
    std::vector<Node*>::iterator it1 = ancestors1.end() - t;
    while(it2!=ancestors2.end()) {
        if (*it1 == *it2) {
            common_ancestor = *it1;
        }
        ++it2;
    }
}
return common_ancestor
```

This code doesn't always work and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Please try to create the smallest and simplest tree that "doesn't always work", and use a debugger to step through the code to help figure out what the problem might be.

Comment: Create function to list ancestrors instead of repeating logic. You have typo btw, as you put `node2`'s ancestros in `ancestors1`

Comment: Only one iterator moves, so you only check for one ancestror.

Comment: just do `++it1; ++it2;` in both the sides of if-else blocks.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I fixed the iterator thing, but it's still somewhat wrong. I'm trying to do what @Some programmer dude said but the test that isn't working is very complicated.

Comment: `it2 = ancestors2.end() - t` - why? both paths must start from root. Couldn't you just iterate both paths from the start and break out as soon as they differ?

Comment: @500 - Internal Server Error I want to iterate over both paths at the same time, which only works if the iterator is pointing to two nodes that are the same height, since the lowest common ancestor is obviously at the same height as itself.

Comment: I don't think we're on quite the same page :) - Say for example that the common ancestor is the third node counted from the root, that's going to be the case in both paths regardless of their respective lengths, no?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: As ancestrors are constructed, we have `{subchildA, childA, root}` (and similarly `{subsubchild, subchildB, childA, root}`, we have to call reverse first

Comment: @Jarod42: Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I couldn't resist.

Aside from the typos and bugs, I believe it can look even simpler:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Node {
  int data;
  Node *parent = nullptr;
};

Node* findCommonAncestor(Node *pNode1, Node *pNode2)
{
  // find paths of pNode1 and pNode2
  std::vector<Node*> path1, path2;
  for (; pNode1; pNode1 = pNode1->parent) path1.push_back(pNode1);
  for (; pNode2; pNode2 = pNode2->parent) path2.push_back(pNode2);
  // revert paths to make indexing simple
  std::reverse(path1.begin(), path1.end());
  std::reverse(path2.begin(), path2.end());
  // compare paths
  Node *pNode = nullptr; // ancestor
  size_t n = std::min(path1.size(), path2.size());
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if (path1[i] == path2[i]) pNode = path1[i];
    else break;
  }
  // done
  return pNode;
}

int main()
{
  // sample tree:
  /*     1
   *     |
   *     2
   *    / \
   *   3   4
   *       |
   *       5
   */
  Node node1 = { 1, nullptr };
  Node node2 = { 2, &node1 };
  Node node3 = { 3, &node2 };
  Node node4 = { 4, &node2 };
  Node node5 = { 5, &node4 };
  Node *pNode = findCommonAncestor(&node3, &node5);
  if (pNode) {
    std::cout << "Lowest common ancestor: " << pNode->data << '\n';
  } else {
    std::cout << "No common ancestor found!\n";
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Lowest common ancestor: 2
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6f58b95f0db084c)

**Note:**

While usage of `iterator`s helps to keep code general…

I would consider this one of the cases where sticking to plain old array (aka `std::vector`) indexing simplifies things.

Comment: Much simpler indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. In addition to needing to move both iterators instead of just one (thanks Jarod42 and v78), I also need to break out of the while loop as soon as I find the lowest common ancestor (otherwise it returns the highest common ancestor).

```
while(it1!=ancestors1.end()) {
        if (*it1 == *it2) {
            common_ancestor = *it1;
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need any extra space to solve this problem in that time:

```
// measure depths
size_t depth1=0;
for (Node *n = node1; n; n=n->parent, ++depth1);
size_t depth2=0;
for (Node *n = node2; n; n=n->parent, ++depth2);

// move the deeper one up until they're the same depth
for (;depth1 > depth2; node1 = node1->parent, --depth1);
for (;depth2 > depth1; node2 = node2->parent, --depth2);

// move them both up until they match
while(node1 != node2) {
    node1 = node1->parent;
    node2 = node2->parent;
}

return node1;
```